# How can I install ng-bootstrap to an nx mono repository?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, ng-bootstrap, nomachine-nx

When trying to install ng-bootstrap into a multi project mono repo using Nx I get the following error:

```bash
npx ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --project=web-app

The add command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
```

I am assuming this is because I am using project.json. It is an Angular project but without angular.json.

Comment: The problem is probably from the schematic that ng-bootstrap uses for an add. That schematic is specifically searching for angular.json (and is therefore not compatible with Nx). I think a manual install is easiest.

Comment: Good point from @MikeOne, the specific `getWorkspace` utility used by ng-bootstrap and many Schematics is quite an issue, it's changing form version to version and is not adapted to all kind of workspaces. But  what is weird is the error message that  @Markus is having. Anyway first question, did you keep angular.json format or switched to project.json ? Because in theory, Nx is compatible with angular.json.

Comment: Hey @AlainBoudard (we know each other :-)). I indeed assumed marcus is using project or workspace.json. I can remember having the same error about a year ago with firebase (before they updated their schematic to also look for workspace/project). There where discussions about nx temporarily generating an angular.json on  an add to accommodate cases like this - but I don’t think they went through with it..

Answer (score 2):

Ok, now as an answer I have this for you :

- If you installed properly Nx AND an Angular project, you should have this message :

```
PS D:\tests\nx\demo> ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --project myapp
Ng add is not natively supported by Nx
Instead, we recommend running `npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap && npx nx g @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap:ng-add`
√ Run this command? (y/N) · true
```

But of course this will fail because the Nx schematics did not handle the --project parameter (there is a PR to be done I guess !) :

```
>  NX  Generating @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap:ng-add

✔ Packages installed successfully.
SchematicsException [Error]: Unable to find project 'undefined' in the workspace
```

So, for your particular case, I'd say you did not choose the Angular option when scaffolding the Nx workspace, or you migrated to project.json ... or you did not run the `ng add` command from the proper directory.